# Extract the £ (pound) currency symbol and the amount (56) from an html file

Tags: eclipse, windows-8, currency, python-3.7, python-unicode

Extract the `£` (pound) currency symbol and the amount (56) from an html file. It is printing the amount as `£56` and prints the currency as `Â`. How can I print only 56, without the symbol? It is working fine with a `$` sign.

Part of the code:

```
       cost= "£56"  
       currencySymbol = cost[0]
       print (currencySymbol, cost[1:])
```

The output I am getting:

```
         Â: £56
```

Comment: Not reproducible: https://ideone.com/z3JkXS

Comment: Please show a [mcve], not just part of it.

Comment: It would help if you completed your example with more surrounding code context.

Comment: finally resolved using open('file.html', encoding="UTF-8")

Comment: @greg-449 i have installed pydev  plugin in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways that you can do it, you can use *split*, *regex* and one method that I did below: 
Hope it helps you

```
import re
cost= "£560,000"
match = re.search(r'([\D]+)([\d,]+)', cost)
output = (match.group(1), match.group(2).replace(',',''))
print (output);

output -->('£', '560000')
```

check here (https://ideone.com/Y053Vb)

Comment: I'm doing to get the symbol of cost i.e '£'

Comment: So? why did you create a character group? How `[\D]` (which is a group that consists of characters of the same class) is different from `\D`? https://ideone.com/yAVPAv

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: i tried to run below code in separate file in eclipse and given error about utf-8.
i search the error and got answer, it is eclipse who is changing unicode style to avoid i used to run in python IDLE, i think we can change unicode in eclipse?.

Thanks to Martijn Pieters
[[SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x91'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092176/syntaxerror-non-utf-8-code-starting-with-x91][1])

```
cost= "£56"  
currencySymbol = cost[0]
print (currencySymbol, cost[1:])
#resolution :when using file use encoding
#with open('index.html', encoding="UTF-8") as productFile:
```